# Executing jar file through java in putty

Tags: java, linux

Here I'm developing a java scheduler. I'm new to java. 
My first task is to execute a jar file through another jar file(can be manually executed) in putty.

I know to execute it in windows.the same way i tried in linux , its not working. this is my code

```
String os_name = System.getProperty("os.name");
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
if(os_name.endsWith("7"))
{
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar","C:\\BMI_calculator.jar");
        Process p = pb.start();

}
else
{
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar","C:\\BMI_calculator.jar");
        Process p = pb.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On linux, this

```
new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar","C:\\BMI_calculator.jar");
```

will not work. Linux does not have a `C:\`. You could use

```
new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar","/home/myuser/BMI_calculator.jar");
```

assuming the jar is in "/home/myuser". I recommend you load that path from a properties file.